# タプルのアンパック

Tags: swift, swift3

タプルのアンパックの方法は　次の方法以外ありませんか？

```
let tp = (10,"aaa", 5.5)

if case let (n,m,f) = tp{
    print(n,m,f)
}
```

let (n:Int,m:String,f:Double) = tp

な感じでアンパックができたらと思っているのですが。。。

Comment: `で文字を括ると部分的にコードブロックが作成できます。ご活用ください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let tp = (10, "aaa", 5.5)
let (n, m, f) = tp
// let (n, m, f): (Int, String, Double) = tp // 型指定を省略しない場合
print("n = \(n), m = \(m), f = \(f)")

// "n = 10, m = aaa, f = 5.5"
```

型指定とか気にせずに、シンプルに対応したら、すぐに解決したのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 型指定と型指定なしでは、それぞれどういう解釈となるのでしょうか

Comment: 「型指定なし」という言葉は、誤解を生みやすいので、意図的に「型指定を省略しない」という言葉を使いました。省略しても、こういう型指定をしたことになっているというニュアンスですね。`(n:Int,m:String,f:Double)`という型指定は間違いで、`(n, m, f): (Int, String, Double)`という型指定が正しいと、受け止めていただければと思います。